# What happens to local variables storing references to deleted NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When I delete an `NSMangedObject` from the database, what happens to local variables who were assigned to it?

For example, I have a simple NSManagedObject:

```
class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var name: String
}
```

And then in my ViewController, I pull it out of the database, and assign it locally:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var myManagedObject: MyManagedObject!
}
```

Then I delete it from the database.

If print the object name I get the following in the console

```
print("myManagedObject.name = \(myManagedObject.name)")
//prints: "myManagedObject.name = "
```

As if the object isn't there?  But if I turn the variable into an optional and check it for nil, I am told it's not nil.

I'm not quite sure how to reconcile this in my mind. There seems to be something pointing to the local variable, but its properties are gone.

If I have many disparate UI objects that rely on that object for its properties, I can't assume that there is some local deep copy of it in memory?

---

Here is more complete code:

In viewDidLoad I create the new object, save the context, fetch the object, then assign it locally.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

      var myManagedObject: MyManagedObject!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //1 Create the new object
            let newObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "MyManagedObject", into: coreDataManager.mainContext) as! MyManagedObject
            newObject.name = "My First Managed Object"

            //2 Save it into the context
            do {
                try coreDataManager.mainContext.save()
            } catch {
                //handle error
            } 

            //3 Fetch it from the database
            let request = NSFetchRequest<MyManagedObject>(entityName: "MyManagedObject")
            do {
                let saved = try coreDataManager.mainContext.fetch(request)
                //4 Store it in a local variable
                self.myManagedObject = saved.first
            } catch {
                 //handle errors
            }
      }
}
```

At this point if I print the local variable's `name` property, I get the correct response:

```
print("The object's name is: \(myManagedObject.name)")
//prints: The object's name is: My First Managed Object
```

So, now I delete it from the database:

```
if let storedObject = myManagedObject { 
     coreDataManager.mainContext.delete(storedObject)
     do {
         try coreDataManager.mainContext.save()
     } catch {
         //handle error
     }
}
```

But now, when I print I get the strangest output:

```
print("myManagedObject.name = \(myManagedObject.name)")
//prints: "myManagedObject.name = "
```

This is totally not the way I'm expecting memory to work. If I create a instance of a class `Foo`, and then pass that instance around to different objects, it's the same instance. It only goes away once no one is pointing to it.

In this case--- what is the variable, `myManagedObject`? It's not `nil`. And what is the string, `name`? Is it an empty string? Or is it some other weird meta-type?

Comment: Show the code where you "assign" it locally. var myManagedObject: MyManagedObject! will just "make" a new variable of type MyManagedObject

Comment: Due to your question update: After you deleted the managed object you marked it as deleted and after you save the database you delete it from the database (not in memory). On managed object you should check isDeleted property or even "fault" property. The object persists in memory as you predicted but its behavior is in your case unpredicted. Anything may happen depending on changes in the framework and empty string seems like a nice workaround for it to still work. It is your job not to use this object after it has been deleted.

Comment: But the rabbit hole goes deeper. If you use multiple contexts and you delete the object on one context it will still exist in the other. But once you will try to apply changes in the second context a conflict will be reported which you will need to resolve. So in memory you will have one instance per context and these instances will be preserved in memory until ARC rules decide to deallocate it. But its properties can change at any time. Ergo the object still exists but its properties are inaccessible. By every right it should crash but it seems the exception was handled for you.

Comment: @MatikOblak - I believe the above two comments are the answer I was looking for. If you would like to move them to your answer I will mark it as accepted. Indeed, checking the isFault property tells me what I needed to know, though I'm still  unclear on why I don't crash. Finding a bug without crashing will be very tough! I tried checking if name == "" and I got true, so CoreData is giving me an empty string...Yikes! Also i think for my case, as you suggested, copying things in memory will be the best for my use. Thanks.

Comment: Since your question is not about how to detect a deleted managed object let's just keep it this way. About finding your error: Have you tried overriding a setter? If you will make sure to research how to do that in core data. Though in your case you might want to override and set a breakpoint into fault setter to find out what deletes it. Still that may not work and if it does not you need to add an observer.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing what you are probably looking here for is the core data context. The context is a connection between your memory and the actual database.

Whenever you fetch the data you fetch it through context. These are managed objects which can be modified or even deleted. Still none of these really happen on the database until you save the context.

When you delete an object it is marked for deletion but it is not deleted from the memory, it must not be since if nothing else it will still be used by the context to actually delete the object from the database itself.

What happens to the managed object once you call to delete it is pretty much irrelevant, even if documented it may change as it is a part of the framework. So it is your responsibility to check these cases and to refetch the objects once needed. So you must ensure your application has a proper architecture and uses core data responsibly.

There are very many ways on how you use your database and more or less any of them has a unique way of using it optimally. You need to be more specific on what you are doing and where do you see potential issues so we can get you on the right track.

To give you an example consider data synchronization from remote server. Here you expect that data can be synchronized at any time no matter what user is doing or what part of the application he is.

For this I suggest you have a single context which operates on a separate thread. All the managed objects should be wrapped and its properties copied once retrieved from database. On most entities you would have something like:

```
MyEntity.findAll { items in
    ...the fetch happens on context thread and returns to main, items are wrappers
}
MyEntity.find(id: idString, { item in
    ...the fetch happens on context thread and returns to main, items are wrappers
})()
```

Then since you do not have any access to the managed object directly you need some kind of method to copy the data to the managed object like:

```
myEntityInstance.commit() // Copies all the data to core data object. The operation is done on a context thread. A callback is usually not needed
```

And then to save the database

```
MyEntity.saveDatabse {
   ... save happens on the context thread and callback is called on main thread
}
```

Now the smart part is that `saveDatabse` method will report to a delegate  that changes have been made. A delegate is usually the current view controller so it makes sense to have a superclass like `DataBaseViewController` which on view did appear assigns itself as a delegate `MyEntity.delegate = self`, on view did load calls some method `reloadData` and in the `databaseDidChange` delegate method calls `reloadData` and same in `viewWillAppear`.

Now each of your view controllers that are subclass of `DataBaseViewController` will override the `reloadData` and in that method you will fetch the data from the database again. Either you are fetching all items or a single one. So for those singe ones you need to save the `id` of the object and fetch it again by that `id`. If the returned object is `nil` then item was deleted so you catch the issue you seem to be mentioning.

All of these things are oversimplified but I hope you get a basic idea about core data and how to use it. It is not easy, it never was and it most likely never will be. It is designed for speed to be able to access the data even from a very large database in shortest time possible. The result is that it might not be very safe.

Comment: When you say: "All the managed objects should be wrapped and its properties copied once retrieved from database." Are you saying that when you use CoreData, once you retrieve your objects from the database, you actually copy all their properties to new unmanaged objects in memory? So you need to create two versions of all your classes: one managed, and one unmanaged.

Comment: In the case I described Yes. But it is for the complexed of cases, it is not something you generally need. It might seem strange at first but once you see that this objects are not just for core data but also for server data (json dictionaries) and UI model which can be used for complex systems such as MVVM and is completely thread safe you might find it very convenient. If you are considering creating this system I suggest you have one superclass which does most of the work, then subclasses only need 2 methods for conversion from and to managed object. Note that core data supports subclassing